# Spark K-Mean Retrieve Cluster Members

Tags: apache-spark-mllib

Can you please provide me sample code snippet to retrieve the cluster members of K mean?

The below code prints cluster centers.  I needed cluster members belonging to each center.

```
val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations) 
clusters.clusterCenters.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   parsedData.foreach(
            new VoidFunction<Vector>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Vector vector) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println(clusters.predict(vector));

                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.